# MySQL, MSSQL - SymmetricDS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, symmetricds

We are trying to replicate our Microsoft SQL Server schema to a MySQL server with SymmetricDS,

I got it running and works ok, but the next step I need to take is to put all of the system tables from SymmetricDS out of the schema we are replicating, to another schema, but I don't really know how can I do it.

And I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction

Thank You!

Comment: hope all tables and all columns have the same names in both databases. otherwise, you'll need table and column transformations and then moving sym_* tables to a separate schema will start making troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install SymmetricDS to the "config" schema. Specify the config schema in the JDBC URL.

When you create your table triggers, you will need to provide the replication schema name. By default SDS will use the config schema.